# Why SCSS classes is not applied/compiled in Nuxt when pushed to production (AWS)?

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I'm developing a website in Nuxt.js. Locally when application is served, the SCSS compiled perfectly and applied on the pages. In my `index.vue` and other components the styles(SCSS) are `scoped`.

When I'm deploying the site to production, suddenly none of the styles (scoped) seem working! But if I remove the `scoped`, it is working on prod as well. But this doesn't feel right way, it totally violated the concept of scoping the styles.

**Can anybody help me here? How can I fix this? I doubt something has to do while building the app.**

**Here is my nuxt.config.js**

```
import path from 'path';

import PurgecssPlugin from 'purgecss-webpack-plugin';
import glob from 'glob-all';
import shrinkRay from 'shrink-ray-current';

require('dotenv').config();

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
   ...
   ...
   ...
  css: ['@/assets/scss/app.scss'],
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-social-sharing', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/Vuelidate' },
    { src: '~/constants', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~plugins/ga.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],
  buildModules: [
    // // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    // '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/stylelint-module
    // '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module'
  ],
  /* Nuxt.js modules */
  modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt', '@nuxtjs/axios', '@nuxtjs/dotenv', 'nuxt-lazy-load'],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false
  },
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (!isDev && isClient) {
        config.plugins.push(
          new PurgecssPlugin({
            paths: glob.sync([
              path.join(__dirname, './pages/**/*.vue'),
              path.join(__dirname, './layouts/**/*.vue'),
              path.join(__dirname, './components/**/*.vue')
            ]),
            whitelist: ['html', 'body']
          })
        );
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Looks like the purge css is extracting out all your css. Try commenting that  out and see if things work.